# how to get [(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)] in my code using python

Tags: python

this is my code :

```
a = [(1,2),(5,6)]
b = [(3,4),(7,8)]

print zip(a,b)
```

and it show :

```
[((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((5, 6), (7, 8))]
```

but i want get :

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
[aa+bb for aa,bb in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(5,6)]
>>> b = [(3,4),(7,8)]
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following list comprehension:

```
[x + y for (i, x) in enumerate(a) for (j, y) in enumerate(b) if i == j]
```

**Result:**

[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]

### Update #2

You can also use **this** list comprehension for your *specific* input:

```
[a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]]
```

which is obviously faster than the `zip` version.

```
from timeit import Timer

s1 = """\
a = [(1, 2), (5, 6)]
b = [(3, 4), (7, 8)]

[x + y for (i, x) in enumerate(a) for (j, y) in enumerate(b) if i == j]
"""

s2 = """\
a = [(1, 2), (5, 6)]
b = [(3, 4), (7, 8)]

[x + y for x, y in zip(a,b)]
"""

s3 = """\
a = [(1, 2), (5, 6)]
b = [(3, 4), (7, 8)]

[a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]]
"""
t1 = Timer(s1)
t2 = Timer(s2)
t3 = Timer(s3)

print ("non-zip: {0} | zip: {1} | list-concat: {2}".format(t1.timeit(), t2.timeit(), t3.timeit()))
```

**Results (Python 2.6.6 on Linux x86-64):**

```
non-zip: 2.17631602287 | zip: 1.20438694954 | list-concat: 0.658749103546
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Note that i'm **not** using the **zip** built-in. Read the *zip* implementation here : http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0201/

Comment: `[item[0] + item[1] for item in (a, b)]` returns `[(1, 2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 7, 8)]`